# Publish node link to social media on content creation

Tags: 7, nodes, social-network

I'm looking for a way to publish the node link to social media (Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin) on the creation of the node.

So what I would like is a little checkbox saying: publish to facebook on the node edit page.
Does anyone know a module that could help me achieve this?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the twitter module:
https://drupal.org/project/twitter

You should be able to then use twitter to send that story to Facebook by hooking up your twitter account to your Facebook account. I'm not sure if the same is possible with linked in though.

Answer (score 0):

I can also suggest using the [Tweet](https://www.drupal.org/project/tweet) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides links to post pages to Twitter in a new window or tab. The tweet will be in focus and will contain customizable text that can hold the relevant URL, title and anything else you need it to (like hashtags). The URL can be automatically abbreviated at the administrator's choice of service by integration with the [Shorten URLs](https://www.drupal.org/project/shorten) module by the same author.
>
> When Twitter is opened, if the user is not already logged in, Twitter will prompt them to log in, and after logging in will redirect users to the tweet form as described above.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Autopost](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost) for Facebook postings. 
[Twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module for Twitter.

Both modules provides integration with rules so you check condition for checkbox.

Have not tried linkedin but [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin) looks promising.
No stable release yet for Drupal 7

Answer (score -1):

Try [social media](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialmedia) module as well.

> The social media module helps integrate your website with social media
>   sites such as Twitter, Facebook and Google+. It provides an
>   centralized way of managing social media profile information and
>   plug-in widgets such as follow and share buttons.